Only Invoke Bedrock FM with Knowledgebase when I ask question about it
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('bedrock-agent-runtime', region_name='us-east-1')
    
    session_id = event.get('sessionId', None)
    
    # https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/bedrock-agent-runtime/client/retrieve_and_generate.html
    
    input_data = {
        'input': {
            'text': event['query']
        },
        'retrieveAndGenerateConfiguration': {
            'knowledgeBaseConfiguration': {
                'knowledgeBaseId': 'WID0XRPRUS',
                'modelArn': 'arn:aws:bedrock:us-east-1::foundation-model/anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0'
            },
            'type': 'KNOWLEDGE_BASE'
        }
    }
    
    if session_id:
        input_data['sessionId'] = session_id
    
    print(input_data)
    
    response = client.retrieve_and_generate(**input_data)
    
    return response


So I configured AWS Bedrock Knowledge Base with Vector Database (Amazon Opensearch Serverless) and tried to test my Knowledge Based Claude3 model.
It worked properly if I asked question about data I put in s3. (in my case, a release note about ios 17, since the latest version just FM Claude know until ios 16)
when I ask sth aout ios 17, it will answer
But if I just say, "hello", or "my name is Douglas" (like the ordinary text), it will say "Sorry, I am unable to assist you with this request."
How can I make the Lambda function that will invoke the FM with knowledgebased only when I ask about sth that's based on the knowledge in s3 bucket, but when I just say no related things like "hello", or other conversations then about 'ios 17', it will invoke the ordinary FM model.
do i have to create seperate lambda function?
